# How to access data binding variable from a BindingAdapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding

Say for instance I have the following variable in my data bound XML.

```xml
<layout ...>
    <data>
        <variable name="listener" type="com.xyz.Listener" />
        <!-- and other variables -->
    </data>
    ...
</layout>
```

I use this variable in every single one of my data-bound layouts, and I need to access it in almost every single one of my `@BindingAdapter`. For instance, my binding adapters mostly look like this.

```
@BindingAdapter("board")
fun setBoard(view: TextView, board: Board) {
    view.setText(board.name)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onBoardClicked(board)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("topic")
fun setTopic(view: TextView, topic: Topic) {
    view.setText(topic.name)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onTopicClicked(topic)
    }
}

// and a few others like that
```

and I use them like this

```xml
<TextView ... app:board="@{board}" ... />
<TextView ... app:topic="@{topic}" ... />
```

What I need here is a way to access that `listener` variable declared in the `data` block to all of my binding adapters. Is there a way to do that without manually passing it as a second variable every single time?

```
// I know I can do this - looking for an alternative
@BindingAdapter({"board", "listener"})
fun setBoard(view: TextView, board: Board, listener: Listener) {
    view.setText(board.name)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onBoardClicked(board)
    }
}
```

I am using Kotlin here, but a solution in Java works just fine for me as well.

Comment: I doubt that what you want is possible. `@BindingAdapter` is applied to Java `static` methods and their Kotlin equivalents. The only things that you have are the parameters and `static`/global stuff (which wouldn't be appropriate here). The best you might hope for is for a way to have the parameter in the function but not have to provide it in the binding expression itself. AFAIK, data binding doesn't offer that sort of automatic parameter injection, though it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some more research, I've just discovered the `DataBindingComponent` interface and it solves precisely the problem I was having. Apparently, if you make your binding adapters instance methods rather than static, the compiler will take the class you declared it in, and add it as a property of `DataBindingComponent`. So I made my binding adapters instance methods, and injected the variable I wanted via the constructor.

```
class Binding(val listener: Listener) {

    @BindingAdapter("board")
    fun setBoard(view: TextView, board: Board) {
        view.setText(board.name)
        view.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onBoardClicked(board)
        }
    }

    @BindingAdapter("topic")
    fun setTopic(view: TextView, topic: Topic) {
        view.setText(topic.name)
        view.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onTopicClicked(topic)
        }
    }
}
```

After building, the compiler generated the following interface

```
package android.databinding;

public interface DataBindingComponent {
    com.my.package.Binding getBinding();
}
```

I then completed the cycle by making the binding class extend this interface and return itself

```
class Binding(val listener: Listener) : DataBindingComponent {
    override fun getBinding(): Binding {
        return this
    }
    // all the other stuff
}
```

This allows me to pass it as an argument when inflating views, and as such I no longer have to even declare `listener` as an XML variable. I can just declare the `Binding` instance

```
val bindingComponent = Binding(object : Listener {
    // implement listener methods here
})
```

and pass it when inflating the layout

```
// now I can use it in activities
DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MyActivityBinding>(
        this, R.layout.my_activity, bindingComponent)

// ...or in fragments
DataBindingUtil.inflate<MyFragmentBinding>(
        inflater, R.layout.my_fragment, parent, false)

// ...or any other place DataBindingUtil allows
```